# Javascript qrcode.decode - how to get the result string

Tags: javascript, decode, qr-code

Ok, my first visit here and my first week doing javaScript, so what could possibly go wrong?

I'm making a web-application for mobile platforms and need a qr-code reader on one page. I am currently testing the scanner example I found at https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/gxbNwy

I get it to open the camera and read the qr-code, however the result string in 
{alert("The Item ID is " + reader.result);} 
is not the string I used to create the code with (in this case '12345'), instead I get the image ascii-gibberish. So, something wrong in the way I try to decode the qr-code.

Here's my javaScript:

```
function openQRCamera(node) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
        node.value = "";
        qrcode.callback = function(res) {
            if(res instanceof Error) {
                alert("No QR code found. Please make sure the QR code is within the camera's frame and try again.");
            } else {
                node.parentNode.previousElementSibling.value = res;
                alert("The Item ID is " + reader.result);
            }
        };
        qrcode.decode(reader.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(node.files[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I had the reader.result instead of the readily formated variable 'res'.

```
alert("The Item ID is " + res);
```

Works fine.